# Spring Boot - Return Empty Json {} instead of Empty Body

Tags: spring-boot, controller, spring-restcontroller

When calling a Rest Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public User getUserById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    return userService.getUserById(id);
}
```

with no user found I want to return `{}` (empty json) instead of a complete empty body. Is there any way to globally convert all returned `null` values into `{}`? (without modifying the method signature, e.g. by switchting to `ResponseEntity`)

Comment: I know you said you don't want to change the method signature, but in a Rest API I'd expect to return an error code if the User can't be found, not empty JSON. Unless there is a really strong reason for not using ResponseEntity, I'd switch to that and return the appropriate error code.

Comment: Yeah! I thought this could somehow be as well achieved by @ControllerAdvice...